# Argument type 'ProtocolName.Protocol' does not conform to expected type 'ProtocolName'`

Tags: swift

When I have a convenience initializer, I get a compiler error, but when I remove that and have one designated initializer, the compiler doesn't complain. What's going on?

I do pass to the constructor a concrete implementation of the protocol.

#### Compiler Issue:

Compiler error: `File.swift:16:20: Argument type 'IngressEventStore.Protocol' does not conform to expected type 'IngressEventStore'`

```swift
public protocol IngressEventStore {
    func doSomething()
}

public class AddEventsToStoreOperation: Operation {
    private let store: IngressEventStore
    var events: [IngressEvent]?

    init(store: IngressEventStore) {
        self.store = store
    }

    convenience init(store: IngressEventStore, events: [IngressEvent]) {

        // !! This line is where it complains
        self.init(store: IngressEventStore)

        self.events = events
    }
}
```

---

#### No Compiler Issues:

```swift
public protocol IngressEventStore {
    func doSomething()
}

public class AddEventsToStoreOperation: Operation {
    private let store: IngressEventStore
    var events: [IngressEvent]?

    init(store: IngressEventStore, events: [IngressEvent]) {
        self.store = store
        self.events = events
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass an actual value to the initialiser

```swift
self.init(store: store)
```